# How to use the substring method in Java

Tags: java, substring

I have 3 strings:

```
String text1 = "abcdefgh";
String text2 = "abcdefghijklmn";
String text3 = "abcdefg";
```

and i want to do something like this:

```
text1.substring(int1, int2);
text2.substring(int1, int2);
text3.substring(int1, int2);
```

that would return abc(the first 3 characters)
the problem is that the strings length is always changing, so i can't use text1.length no matter what.

Comment: Why not use text1 = text1.substring(0,3); ??

Comment: Do you always need first 3 characters then why not set int1 = 0 and int2 = 3? What is the problem actually in doing that? Do you expect the string to be less than 3 characters in cases. Even if length of strings change still substring should work for index 0 and 3 if string is greater than 3 characters.

Answer (score 6):

If the length is changing, do a check first

```
if (textStr != null && textStr.length() >= 3) {
    newStr = textStr.substring(0, 3);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer:

```
.substring(0, 3)
```

Comment: How is it different from my comment? Does the question even make sense? It should be renamed to "How to use the substring method"

Comment: This will fail if the string is short than 3 characters or null. Do what @Dragan suggests.

Answer (score 0):

Because the string length can vary (or perhaps even be null) you'd be better off writing something a little more general purpose.  In your example your test strings are always longer than 3 characters, but is that always the case? You could also write this function to automatically pad the string to your desired length.

```
public static String variableLengthSubstring(String text, int length) {
    StringBuilder substring = new StringBuilder();
    if(text != null) {
        int i = 0;
        length = Math.min(length, text.length());
        while(substring.length() < length) {
            substring.append(text.charAt(i++));
        }
    }
    return substring.toString();
}
```